# Raspberry pi compute module 4 io board and compute module power on with PoE

Tags: pi-4, compute-module-3, compute-module

I have rpi cmb4 and I want to power on rpi with using PoE. I don't know how should I do. I tried to just connect ethernet cable to rpi but rpi was still closed.

Is there any idea?

Answer (score 0):

PoE runs at 48V, it has to be stepped down to 5V. RPI does not have circuitry for that.
You need either a [PoE HAT](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/poe-hat/) or a **PoE USB splitter**.

Comment: For CM4IO I would use 12V to get the full functionality of the IO board https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/compute-module-4-io-board/

Comment: Actually I have trouble understanding because I am new to this business. Sorry for that. I mean, unlike normal raspberry, can I supply PoE for the raspberry pi cm4 io board without needing a PoE HAT? @Dirk